# Excel - Find and List emailaddress based on domain address

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, email

I have a list of 6000 email address with 5 different address suffix. I want to list the email address based on their address suffix. So how  do i sort this in Excel.
The suffix address are based on the location and i'm trying add them to different mail group. So i neeed to list them separtely.
I would be grateful for anyones help.
Example in the excel. This has only one column that list all the email address
Name1@in.su.net,Name2@cn.su.net, Name3@jp.su.net etc.....
So i would like to list the ones that has @in.su.net

Comment: Some samples of your data and the 5 suffixes will get you a better answer.

Comment: Hi, i have edited my question. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: If you have a Linux machine at hand, the answer is as simple as: `grep '@in.su.net' my_email_file` and the result will be immediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a helper column to help with sorting.

First we define the "groups" for each suffix. These are represented in columns F & G below. If you have 5 suffixes, then you would have 5 groups. These data will be used in a vlookup formula.

Next, column B is your helper columm with this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",A2)+1),$F$1:$G$4,2,FALSE)
```

Starting from the inside with the `RIGHT` formula, it's returing everything after the @ sign, to include the @ sign, from the cell in column A. Then it's using these data in the vlookup against column F and returning column G value.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me :) I can now filter the groups and add them in my mail group.